# php poor man's cache

Tags: php, caching

I have some small sets of data from the database (mysql) who are seldom updated.
Basically 3 or 4 small bi dimensional arrays (50-200 items).
This is the ideal case for memcached, but I'm on a shared server and can't install anything.
I only have PHP and MySQL.

I'm thinking about storing the arrays on file and regenerate the file via a cron job every 2-3 hours.

Any better idea or suggestion about this approach?
What's the best way to store those arrays?

Comment: Do you experience at this moment any performance problems related to these arrays?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I have to get this info from the database for EVERY page.  
And MySQL is dying cause of the load...

Comment: @ILMV jslint??? I think you pasted the wrong link...

Comment: Yeah, it's ok. 99% of sites doing that. That's what database were invented for  - getting info for every page. You have nothing to worry about. And if your database dying, you have to do a `profiling` first, to make yourself know, what query causing this.

Comment: Yeah, but in 99% of the sites The database server works ok. This is not the case... Every query to the database take ages, no mater how simple they are, no mater how good is the query plan

Comment: So, more of that you **desperately** need to **profile** your application, instead of blind shooting in the air

Comment: Retrieving this data from MySQL takes 200-500ms. The query itself takes 0-2ms. The roundtrip is my problem.
I need to reduce the queries to the database to the minimum because every single query adds 200-500ms to the execution time

Comment: @The Disintegrator .. oh shit, yeah that was meant to be for a different question, my bad :D

Comment: @The Disintegrator a roundtrip of 200-500ms is way too much, this sounds like a configuration problem. This can certainly be helped using a filesystem based caching mechanism but it would be better to fix the underlying query as @Col says. Can you tell more about your DB configuration and show some of the queries that take so long?

Comment: I can't do ANYTHIG about the mysql configuration because I'm on a shared server.
Those times are the the server is very busy (not necessarily with my page, but with the other users).

I have a table with the categories for products with 81 record, this table has the description for every category.
catID, catName, catDesc no joins no nothing, a simple select of 81 rows.
The query is not the problem. The problem is the server and I can't do anything about it. I will change to a better hosting company but right now I need so solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with an overworked MySQL server then yes, cache that data into a file. Then you have two ways to update your cache: either via a cron job, unconditionally, every N minutes (I wouldn't update it less frequently than every hour) or everytime the data changes. The best approach depends on your specific situation. In general, the cron job way is the simplest but the on-change way pretty much guarantees that you won't ever use stale data.

As for the storage format, you could just serialize() the array and save the string to a file. With big arrays, unserialize() is faster than a big array(...) declaration.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, it would be better to check whether the root of the problem can't be fixed first. A roundtrip that long sounds like a network configuration problem.

Otherwise, if the DB simply *is* that slow, nothing speaks against a filesystem based cache. You could turn each query into an `md5()` hash, and use that as a file name. `Serialize()` the result set into the file and fetch it from there. Use `filemtime()` to determine whether the cache file is older than x hours. If it is, regenerate the query - or in fact, to avoid locking problems on the cache files, use a cron job to regenerate it.

Just note that this way, you would be dealing with whole result sets that you have to load into your script's memory all at once. You wouldn't have the advantage of being able to query a result set row by row. This can be done too in a cached way, but it's more complicated.

Comment: I think I'll use an hybrid of yours, carlos and Josh answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

My english is not good, sorry.

Some times I have read about any alternative to memcache. Is complex, but I think that you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php acceding to shared memory.

A simple class example used for storing data is here:
http://apuntesytrucosdeprogramacion.blogspot.com/2007/12/php-variables-en-memoria-compartida.html

Is written in spanish, sorry, but the code is easy to understand (Eliminar=delete)

I never have test this code!! and I don't know if it's viable in a shared server.

Comment: Mi ingles tampoco debe ser muy bueno, a juzgar por la cantidad de comentarios que necesite poner para que entiendan de que hablaba...
Lo mirare mas tarde, ahora necesito dormir un poco, gracias